# Can I use a network token PAN with a payment gateway where a standard PAN is expected?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, applepay

For example, if you refer to the Apple Pay documentation for their [Payment Token Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html), you'll find the following structure is decryptable:
[image: Payment Data Keys]

Since the `applicationPrimaryAccountNumber` is a PAN—albeit a network token PAN—my question is will a payment gateway like Stripe, Checkout.com, Adyen, etc. accept the PAN as a "normal" PAN when I attempt to charge it? Or do gateways differentiate the PAN since it's a network one and disallow it?

For example, Checkout.com's API requires you to distinguish the PAN as a network token PAN (see [here](https://api-reference.checkout.com/#operation/requestAPaymentOrPayout) and set the `source` to `network_token`).

Stripe on the other hand seems to only want to allow you to create network tokens (ApplePay, GooglePay) using their UI elements.

Since this is a limitation on Stripe, and possibly other payment gateways, I'm wondering if network tokens were designed to be usable as PAN's alone, almost in a "backwards-compatible" way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering the same thing. We've used Visa Network Tokens with our current processor. However, I can't seem to find any indication that the Stripe API will let you create a Payment Method with the Network Token.

Upon creating the payment, I would expect to provide the Cryptogram. I can't seem to find any mention of this in their API, which makes me think they don't support this at the merchant layer (only internally).

(edit)
After doing some digging in the API, I'm wondering if they'll let you use the tokenized PAN as the card number and pass in the cryptogram as the CVC update.